# JObject parse returns extra curly braces

Tags: c#, json

I have a variable `projectData` that contains a valid json string that is stored in a database.

After doing the following:

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj = JObject.Parse(projectData);
```

Instead of getting

```
{
"devices": {
    "device_A": {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "test",
        "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I get this instead:

```
    {{
        "devices": {
            "device_A": {
                "id": "12345",
                "name": "test",
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    }}
```

So basically an aditional `{` and `}` were added to my json string.

I have also tried the following:

```
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(projectData);
```

and it didnt work.

Why is this a problem to me?

I want to iterate over the `obj["devices"]` array, and when I do the following

```
foreach(var d in obj["devices"])
```

It simply doesnt work because of the double curly braces.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "I get this instead". `Parse()` doesn't produce JSON. Are you just inferring that from the behavior you're seeing or are you actually seeing that JSON with the double curly braces somewhere?

Comment: how do you see the double curly braces? are you seeing that in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Jawad, yes in debug mode in visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
"devices": {
    "device_A": {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "test",
        "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Your json shows devices as a json object and not an array. You cannot iterate over it with a for loop.

You can access the data by parsing it first and then accessing the properties by using the [] brackets.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(obj["devices"]["device_A"]["id"].Value<string>());

//prints
12345

// To Loop through multiple devices... you can use this.
foreach (var device in ((JObject)obj["devices"]).Properties())
    Console.WriteLine(obj["devices"][device.Name]["id"]);
```

Also, when you are using the debug mode, the watch or locals will show `{{ }}` because the braces are escaped.

---

**Array version of Json**

If your json looked like below, then you can use the for loop to access the elements of the JArray.

```
{
"devices": [
    {
      "device_A": {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "test",
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

with the above json, you can use the for loop in the following way,

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var device in obj["devices"])
    Console.WriteLine(device["device_A"]["id"]);

// Prints
12345
```

Comment: @PedroMartins I added an update to the post above that shows you how you can iterate through multiple devices when devices is "not" an array.

Comment: The thing is, I will not know the name of the device. I wont know it its named "Device_A"

Comment: @PedroMartins Correct.. thats why i added the update to my first section of the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Jawad, this solved my problem.
I cannot control the json i receive, unfortunately its not an array in the devices